# Roslyn fails to compile a trivial project

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am trying to use Roslyn to compile a trivial project but it fails.

Consider the following setup (assuming c:\temp exists and you have .NET 6 installed):

1. mkdir c:\temp\TestLib
2. notepad c:\temp\TestLib\TestLib.csproj

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
       <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
       <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
     </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
3. notepad c:\temp\TestLib\SomeClass.cs

   ```
   namespace TestLib
   {
     public class SomeClass
     {
       void DoThings()
       {
         Console.WriteLine("Things!");
       }
     }
   }
   ```
4. cd c:\temp\TestLib
5. dotnet build

   *Result: Build succeeded*
6. mkdir c:\temp\RoslynTrouble
7. notepad c:\temp\RoslynTrouble\RoslynTrouble.csproj

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
       <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
       <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
       <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.5.5" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="3.8.0" />
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="3.8.0" />
     </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
8. notepad c:\temp\RoslynTrouble\Program.cs

   ```
   using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
   using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

   class TestProgram
   {
     public static async Task Main(string[] args)
     {
       string csprojPath = args[0];
       var instance = MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
       Console.WriteLine(instance.Name + ": " + instance.Version);
       var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
       var project = await workspace.OpenProjectAsync(csprojPath);
       var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
       if (compilation == null)
       {
         Console.WriteLine("Error: unexpected null compilation");
         return;
       }
       foreach (var diagnostic in compilation.GetDiagnostics())
       {
         Console.WriteLine(diagnostic);
       }
     }
   }
   ```
9. cd c:\temp\RoslynTrouble
10. dotnet run c:\temp\TestLib\TestLib.csproj

- Expected result: no errors
- Actual result: lots of compilation errors:

```
.NET Core SDK: 6.0.203
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(2,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(3,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(4,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(5,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(6,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(7,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(8,1): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\SomeClass.cs(7,13): error CS0103: The name 'Console' does not exist in the current context
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(2,8): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(8,8): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.AssemblyInfo.cs(11,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(7,8): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(6,8): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(2,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(3,8): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.AssemblyInfo.cs(12,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(4,8): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(5,8): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
c:\open\prototypes\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(3,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
```

What am I missing and how can I fix those errors?

Comment: Note: this is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698247/roslyn-code-analysis-returns-false-build-errors-from-an-error-free-solution but I don't think I'm using wrong packages - my question contains all of the steps needed to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you'll find the modifications described in a `Note`. Try the following:

1. `mkdir c:\temp\TestLib`
2. `notepad c:\temp\TestLib\TestLib.csproj`
3. Click `Yes`

   [image]

   **TestLib.csproj**:

   ```
   <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
     <PropertyGroup>
       <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
       <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
       <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
     </PropertyGroup>
   </Project>
   ```
4. Save As (save with "UTF-8" encoding)
5. `notepad c:\temp\TestLib\SomeClass.cs`
6. Click `Yes`

   [image]

   **SomeClass.cs**:

   **Note**: Made the method `public` - not much point in having a class with one method and making it `private`.

   ```
   namespace TestLib
   {
       public class SomeClass
       {
           public void DoThings()
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Things!");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
7. Save As (save with "UTF-8" encoding)

---

8. `mkdir c:\temp\RoslynTrouble`
9. `notepad c:\temp\RoslynTrouble\RoslynTrouble.csproj`
10. Click `Yes`

    [image]

    **RoslynTrouble.csproj**:

    **Note**: Use version `4.4.0` for `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild`.

    ```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
            <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
            <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
            <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        </PropertyGroup>
        <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Build.Locator" Version="1.5.5" />
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="4.4.0" />
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild" Version="4.4.0" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
    ```
11. Save As (save with "UTF-8" encoding)
12. `notepad c:\temp\RoslynTrouble\Program.cs`
13. Click `Yes`

    [image]

    **Program.cs**:

    **Note**: Added namespace `RoslynTrouble`. Changed class name to `Program` to match the filename (Program.cs).

    ```
    using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
    using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

    namespace RoslynTrouble
    {
        public class Program
        {
            public static async Task Main(string[] args)
            {
                string csprojPath = args[0];
                var instance = MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
                Console.WriteLine(instance.Name + ": " + instance.Version);
                var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
                var project = await workspace.OpenProjectAsync(csprojPath);
                var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();

                if (compilation == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: unexpected null compilation");
                    return;
                }

                foreach (var diagnostic in compilation.GetDiagnostics())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(diagnostic);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ```
14. Save As (save with "UTF-8" encoding)

---

15. `cd c:\temp\RoslynTrouble`
16. `dotnet run "C:\temp\TestLib\TestLib.csproj"`

**Note**: The double-quotes in the command above are optional since there aren't any spaces in the path.

---

**Result**:

**Note**: The result has warnings, but no errors.

```
.NET Core SDK: 6.0.301
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(2,7): hidden CS8933: The using directive for 'System' appeared previously as global using
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.AssemblyInfo.cs(10,7): hidden CS8933: The using directive for 'System' appeared previously as global using
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(5,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(3,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(4,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.AssemblyInfo.cs(11,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(2,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(8,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs(3,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.AssemblyInfo.cs(10,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(7,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
C:\temp\TestLib\obj\Debug\net6.0\TestLib.GlobalUsings.g.cs(6,1): hidden CS8019: Unnecessary using directive.
```

---

If one would like to avoid displaying warnings, one could use the following alternative code for `Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace RoslynTrouble
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool errorsExist = false;
            string csprojPath = args[0];
            var instance = MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();
            Console.WriteLine(instance.Name + ": " + instance.Version);
            var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            var project = await workspace.OpenProjectAsync(csprojPath);
            var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();

            if (compilation == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: unexpected null compilation");
                return;
            }

            foreach (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostic diagnostic in compilation.GetDiagnostics())
            {
                if (diagnostic.Severity != Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticSeverity.Hidden &&
                    diagnostic.Severity != Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticSeverity.Warning)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(diagnostic);
                    errorsExist = true;
                }
            }

            if (!errorsExist)
                Console.WriteLine($"Successfully compiled '{args[0]}'.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Resources**:

- [Roslyn Code Analysis returns false build errors from an error free solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58698247/roslyn-code-analysis-returns-false-build-errors-from-an-error-free-solution)

Comment: Thank you for the very, very detailed answer - I can definitely see you went through a lot of trouble to fully test it end-to-end and you also fixed a bug in TestLib :)

Now, the gist of it is that CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.MSBuild 3.8.0 do the wrong thing but it's been fixed in 4.4.0 :)

I am sad that there are still warnings - it feels like the dotnet codegens are doing something wrong, with GlobalUsings.g.cs generating useless things. I would have preferred zero warnings but not by masking them :)