# How to use Roslyn in wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, roslyn, initializecomponent

When the same .cs file is compiled into a DLL using Visual Studio, it can run normally in a WPF program. However, when compiling into a DLL using Roslyn, it will cause an error in all windows' InitializeComponent method: "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context."

The runtime is .Net7, here is the core code:

```
void CompileCode(string codeString)
{
    SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(codeString);
    var references = new[]
    {
        typeof(object).Assembly,
        Assembly.Load("SqlSugar"),
        Assembly.Load("System.Linq"),
        Assembly.Load("netstandard"),
        Assembly.Load("System.Runtime"),
        Assembly.Load("System"),
    }
    .Select(assembly => assembly.Location)
        .Distinct()
        .Select(l => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(l))
        .Cast<MetadataReference>()
        .ToArray();
    var DefaultNamespaces =
            new[]
            {
                "System",
                "System.IO",
                "System.Net",
                "System.Linq",
                "System.Text",
                "System.Text.RegularExpressions",
                "System.Collections.Generic"
            };
    var compilationOptions = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary)
            .WithPlatform(Platform.AnyCpu) 
            .WithOverflowChecks(true)
            .WithOptimizationLevel(OptimizationLevel.Release) 
            .WithUsings(DefaultNamespaces);
    ;
    var runtimePath = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(); 
    CSharpCompilation cSharpCompilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(tableName)
                    .WithOptions(compilationOptions) 
                    .AddReferences(references) 
                    .AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);
    var assemblyPath = @"D:\myCode\DataTableCS\" + tableName + ".dll";
    var pdbPath = @"D:\myCode\DataTableCS\" + tableName + ".pdb";
    var dll_result = cSharpCompilation.Emit(assemblyPath, pdbPath);     
    
}
```

cs file as below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SqlSugar;

namespace CommonClass
{
    ///<summary>
    ///
    ///</summary>
    [SugarTable("Tb_Project")]
    public partial class Tb_Project
    {
           public Tb_Project(){


           }
           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:False
           /// </summary>           
           [SugarColumn(IsPrimaryKey=true)]
           public string ID {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public string? Name {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public decimal? Quantity {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public string? RootItemID {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public string? RootItemConfig {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public string? ProjectNo {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public string? ProjectManagerID {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public string? MDPTime {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public string? Status {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public string? Description {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public int? Version {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public string? CTime {get;set;}

           /// <summary>
           /// Desc:
           /// Default:
           /// Nullable:True
           /// </summary>           
           public int? del {get;set;}

    }
}
```

1: Creat a sample wpf C# application
2: then use the CompileCode() to produce the dll by the .cs file
3: attach the dll produced in step 2 to the application
4: windows raises the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Roslyn fails to compile a trivial project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75490394/roslyn-fails-to-compile-a-trivial-project)

Comment: That error should accompany a specific window, please update the question with the failing window's cs code and the top part of the xaml of the same window.

In my experience InitializeComponent not existing is usually a mismatch in namespaces between the cs and xaml.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Slipoch I have added the cs file in the post. You can follow the steps in the post. That's all the code. Don't forget to add the dependency, such as SqlSugar.Core, Microsoft CodeAnalysis Common and CSharp...

Comment: I have had come across intermittent weird issues with sugar previously. 

But in other news you may need to use the Update-Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform -r command to get rosyln working properly in your project. (you may have to include it's library as one of your assemblies)

I guess what are you trying to do? Why are you trying to use roslyn external to VS to compile?

Comment: @Slipoch I hope this program can automatically update entity code and generate DLL files after the database fields change, so that I don't have to reprogram the entire program each time

Comment: Otherwise, it's a .net7 application, can not use CodeDom.