HttpClient .NET 4
I'm currently creating a app that needs to download some raw data from the internet, the problem is that the app is compiled by another C# app (builder), so I'm using the CSharpCodeProvider which generates .NET 4 assemblies.
The problem now is that when using WebClient or HttpClient in .NET 4, I get this error:

Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Is there a method to download stuff like that in .NET 4?
Download function:
static async Task<byte[]> GetData()
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(Url);
    return await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}

Compiler:
var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } };
using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions))
{
    var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters
    {
        GenerateExecutable = true,
        OutputAssembly = outputExe
    };

    if (iconFile != null)
        compilerParameters.CompilerOptions = $@"/win32icon:""{iconFile}""";

    if (references != null && references.Length > 0)
        compilerParameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(references);

    CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(compilerParameters, sourceCode);

    if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
    {
        string errors = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().Select(e => e.ErrorText));
        MessageBox.Show($"Compilation failed:{Environment.NewLine}{errors}", "WT Error");
    }
}

I tried to get raw data from internet, but I got an error.

.NET 4.0 was retired in 2016. I would expect that by now it may well be suffering from numerous security problems - I'd be really, really worried if you actually had to use .NET 4.0. Does this app builder that you're using really not support anything more up-to-date? (It's not clear to me why you're writing code to compile code, if the app builder is also going to compile the app... clarifying the context here would help a lot.)

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74800036/10024425

@JonSkeet its the compiler lib by .net and it only goes up to 4 as far as i know, the builder compiles code that has customizable values for the user thats why its compiled at runtime after the user made the customization

@user246821 how doesnt it? its about httpclient not working in .net 4?

@Weylcan: If the requirement is just "build C# code programmatically" then you can use Roslyn. That's very different from "you can only use the .NET 4 framework". Again, your context is really unclear...

@user246821 how does a config file help if the lib isnt working?

The following may be of interest: Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with .NET Framework

@Weylcan: how does a config file help if the lib isnt working: It's useful for debugging the issue.

Here's a post for using Roslyn: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75491224/10024425.

You need to determine what version of TLS is needed, make sure that your OS supports it, and make sure that it's enabled. Enabling network debugging will help with determining what version of TLS is needed/supported.

If you switch to .NET, the following may be of interest: TLS/SSL best practices

The TLS issue that you've encountered, wouldn't likely exist if you used the latest .NET or .NET Framework, as well as, the latest operating system (ie: Win 11).  You may consider adding the operating system that you're using to your post

By newing HttpClient each time, you leak sockets. You lack explicit TLS 1.2 switch set to on.

@user246821 Thanks, I used the ServicePointManager to set it to TLS 1.2 and now it workes
